# Python cannot read a file which contains a specific string

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I've written a function to remove certain words and characters for a string. The string in question is read into the program using a file. The program works fine except when a file, anywhere, contains the following anywhere in the body of the file.

> Security Update for Secure Boot (3177404) This security update
>   resolves a vulnerability in Microsoft Windows. The vulnerability could
>   allow Secure Boot security features to be bypassed if an attacker
>   installs an affected policy on a target device. An attacker must have
>   either administrative privileges or physical access to install a
>   policy and bypass Secure Boot.

I've never experienced such weird behavior. Anybody have any suggestions?

This is the function I've written.

```
def scrub(file_name):
    try:
        file = open(file_name,"r")
        unscrubbed_string = file.read()
        file.close()

        cms = open("common_misspellings.csv","r")
        for line in cms:
            replacement = line.strip('\n').split(',')
            while replacement[0] in unscrubbed_string:
                unscrubbed_string = unscrubbed_string.replace(replacement[0],replacement[1])

        cms.close()

        special_chars = ['.',',',';',"'","\""]

        for char in special_chars:
            while char in unscrubbed_string:
                unscrubbed_string = unscrubbed_string.replace(char,"")

        unscrubbed_list = unscrubbed_string.split()

        noise = open("noise.txt","r")
        noise_list = []

        for word in noise:
            noise_list.append(word.strip('\n'))

        noise.close()

        for noise in noise_list:
            while noise in unscrubbed_list:
                    unscrubbed_list.remove(noise)
        return unscrubbed_list

    except:
        print("""[*] File not found.""")
```

Comment: You need to indent the body of the function.

Comment: Put print statements in your script so you can see how far it's getting before it hangs.

Comment: You should also learn to use `with` to open files and close them automatically. And use the `csv` module to read a CSV file.

Comment: You should look at the exception. It may tell you everything.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I tried. But when it remove try/catch and run the program it still hangs and then the only thing i can do is press the ctrl+z thus ending the program. But ill try to delve into the exceptions.

Comment: Oh, so it does not throw an exception? It should be a basic debugging exercise, if it's getting stuck in a loop.

Comment: I'll bet replacement[0] in replacement[1] somewhere, if it's hanging.

Comment: "works fine except when X is the case..."   Well, what *does* happen when X is the case?   But yes, Kenny is right: the flaw that leaps out from a cursory code review is that, if `replacement[0]` is ever a substring of `replacement[1]`, the `while` loop will never terminate. `re.sub`  from the `re` module will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may be hanging because your `.replace()` call is in a `while` loop. If, for any particular line of your `.csv` file, the `replacement[0]` string is a *substring* of its corresponding `replacement[1]`, and if either of them appears in your critical text, then the `while` loop will never finish.  In fact, you don't need the `while` loop at all—a single `.replace()` call will replace all occurrences.

But that's only one example of the problems you'll encounter with your current approach of using a blanket `unscrubbed_string.replace(...)`   You'll either need to use *regular expression* substitution (from the `re`) module, or break your string down into words yourself and work word-by-word instead.  Why?  Well, here's a simple example: `'Teh'` needs to be corrected to `'The'`—but what if the document contains a reference to `'Tehran'`? Your "Secure Boot" text will contain an example analogous to this.

If you go the regular-expression route, the symbol `\b` solves this by matching word boundaries of any kind (start or end of string, spaces, punctuation).  Here's a simplified example:

```
import re

replacements = {
    'Teh':'The',
}
unscrubbed = 'Teh capital of Iran is Tehran. Teh capital of France is Paris.'

better = unscrubbed
naive = unscrubbed
for target, replacement in replacements.items():
    naive = naive.replace(target, replacement)

    pattern = r'\b' + target + r'\b'
    better = re.sub(pattern, replacement, better)

print(unscrubbed)
print(naive)
print(better)
```

Output, with mistakes emphasized:

> ***Teh*** capital of Iran is Tehran. ***Teh*** capital of France is Paris. (`unscrubbed`)
>
> The capital of Iran is ***Theran***. The capital of France is Paris. (`naive`)
>
> The capital of Iran is Tehran. The capital of France is Paris. (`better`)